# Stack overflow error when i try to assign a new pointer to a structure

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, binary-search-tree

When I call the function `newNode` an exception is thrown and says `stack overflow`, I checked the parameters of the node in it says that they can't be read.

```
             struct node
            {
                int data;
                struct node* left;
                struct node* right;
            };

            //function that initialeze a new node
            struct node* newNode(int data) {
                struct node *node = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                node->data = data;
                node->left = NULL;
                node->right = NULL;

                return node;
            }

        struct node* arrayToBST(int arr[], int start, int end) {
            int mid = (start + end) / 2;

            struct node *root = newNode(arr[mid]);

            root->left = arrayToBST(arr, start, mid - 1);
            root->right = arrayToBST(arr, start, mid + 1);


            return root;
        }
```

Comment: consider what happens in your arrayToBST function when start == end...

Comment: @ChrisDodd that was one of the problems .But it didn't solve the esue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `newNode` is fine, the real problem is in your function `arrayToBST`.
You are trying to build the tree recursively, but you didn't give it a stop point, for example:

```cpp
struct node* arrayToBST(int arr[], int start, int end) {
  if (start > end) return NULL;
  int mid = (start + end) / 2;
  ...
```

Therefore your program will call `arrayToBST` function endlessly until the stack overflow.